# jpcap exception

Tags: java, jpcap

While running my code I got this exception. I did not get what is it?

```clj
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  
    jpcap.JpcapCaptor.nativeOpenOffline(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.nativeOpenOffline(Native Method)
        at jpcap.JpcapCaptor.openFile(JpcapCaptor.java:90)
        at EWMAStableIP.getNumOfNewIPs(EWMAStableIP.java:106)
        at EWMAStableIP.initial(EWMAStableIP.java:343)
        at Frame.initialize(Frame.java:78)
        at Frame.<init>(Frame.java:52)
        at Frame$1.run(Frame.java:39)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Comment: Yes,something is wrong in your code.I agreed.

Comment: and what maybe be wrong??!!

Comment: Which code cause that exception ?

Comment: I did not write this code but when I try to use i a Frame.java i got this error. i do not know what you want to know?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Exception+in+thread+%22AWT-EventQueue-0%22+java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError%3A+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: I do this work but it does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

In order to run appropriately, jpcap needs a native libray to be installed - it's missing on your system though.

See the documentation delivered with jpcap in order to get it properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you jpcap is not configured properly.
Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591880/jpcap-jpcap-library-path

Also look if a native AWT library is missing in Java.